# Formatting java.time Instant values from PostgreSQL Timestamp values

Tags: java, postgresql, date-format, jooq, java-time

I'm new to the java.time formats in Java 8 and later, but I'm reasonably comfortable with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and I'm very familiar with Java's `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `DateFormat` classes along with ISO 8601.

I'm using [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org) 9.3 with [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) 3.6.4, with a `foo` table column containing a timestamp:

```
bar timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I retrieve that `bar` value using jOOQ, and try to print it out using java.time's `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`:

```
DateTimeFormatter timestampFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
Cursor<FooRecord> fooRecordCursor = createDSLContext().selectFrom(FOO).fetchLazy();
for(FooRecord fooRecord : fooRecordCursor) {
  System.out.println(timestampFormatter.format(fooRecord.getBar().toInstant());
}
```

This throws an `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException`:

```
Caused by: java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: Year
  at java.time.Instant.getLong(Instant.java:608)
  at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext$1.getLong(DateTimePrintContext.java:205)
  at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:298)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2543)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2182)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2182)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2182)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1745)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1719)
```

But if I use my own custom `ISO8601DateFormat` which extends the old-school `SimpleDateFormat`, I can parse the value just fine:

```
final DateFormat timestampFormatter = new ISO8601DateFormat();
...
  System.out.println(timestampFormatter.format(fooRecord.getBar());
```

I find this very confusing:

- The jOOQ `bar` field accessor returns a `java.sql.Timestamp`. In the Java 8 version I convert that to an `Instant`, but why would that reduce the amount of information available?
- An `Instant` is supposed to be an absolute point of time --- isn't it simply based upon a `long` offset just like JodaTime and Java `Date`?
- Why is `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` expecting a `Year` field from an `Instant`? Shouldn't the formatter just convert the `long` offset to a date/time in the current time zone, and retrieve the year from that? I wouldn't expect *any* instant to contain a `Year` field.

In short: **If my `SimpleDateFormat`-based `ISO8601DateFormat` works fine for a `Timestamp` from PostgreSQL, why can't `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` figure out how to format the `Instant` version of the same value?**

Comment: Did you try `.toLocalDateTime()` instead?

Comment: `toLocalDatetime()` wouldn't work either as it misses the time zone field needed for `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` format.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
It's because the `java.time` classes are separating the concepts "point in time" and "time as a human sees it" whereas `Timestamp`/`Date` don't.

**Long answer:**
You are right, an `Instant` is representing a single point in the time line. That's why it is not possible to give a correct/unique answer to the question "what's the year/day/time?". It depends on where on the world the question is asked: In New York it differs from Sidney.
But your `DateTimeFormatter` is asking exactly this question. And that is why you get an `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException`.

`Date` and its subclass `Timestamp` on the other hand are mixing up the two concepts. While internally storing a `long` "point in time", they "answer" if asked for their year. Usually they are assuming the local time zone of the system to pin the the `long`-offset to an specific time zone.
This is error-prone and let to introduction of `Calendar`, JodaTime and java.time.

Now, why is your `DateTimeFormatter` not smart enough to align `Instant` to the default TimeZone?
`DateTimeFormatter` works on the [`TemporalAccessor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html) interface and does not differ between concrete implementations like `Instant`, `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`. There are   legitimate formatting cases for all of those implementations and I assume it is simply not feasible to check the concrete object's compatibility with the given format let alone to perform correct conversions.

The solution:
You have to align your timestamp to a timezone/offset yourself:

```
System.out.println(timestampFormatter.format(
    fooRecord.getBar().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```